# how to convert json string back to an object in Angular 8

Tags: json, angular, object

I converted this object into JSON string.
values of **subject1, subject2, subject 3** are coming from input fields in angular frontend

```
subject = {
    "subject1": "A",
    "subject2": "B",
    "subject3": "C"
}
```

and now I have a JSON string like this,

> const subjects = {"subject1": "A", "subject2": "B","subject3":"c"}

Like this, I saved this as a JSON string in DB. In another place, I wanted to access this string as an object as previously I made.
to output these subjects separately as same as It gets as an object.

> example:- First input box - subject1 value as **A** , Second input box - subject2 value as **B**

How can I put them back again like separate values into separate variables or any other way to separate them and put back into the text fields?

I just tried to get that JSON string and tried to access subject1 like
`subject1 = subjects.subject1`  like that I can put subject1 in relevant text field.
But that doesn't work. I checked previous questions like this. But they didn't answer my question. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `JSON.parse`.

```
  const obj = JSON.parse(subjects);
  console.log(obj.subject1);  // "A"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **destructuring assignment**:

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.

```js
const subject = {
    "subject1": "A",
    "subject2": "B",
    "subject3": "C"
}

const {subject1,subject2,subject3} = subject;

console.log(subject1);
console.log(subject2);
console.log(subject3);
```

You can find more about destructuring assignment [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: That's cool. Thank you. I was looking for this for a long time.